# Android: ListView with Blank Data

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I'm having troubles with an development, it's my first android application with Eclipse JUNO.
I want to populate a Listview in a ListActivity with public static variables, assigned correctly (with debugger i check that).
The problem is that the listview is showing me the correct numbers of rows, but with blank data.

He is my code:

Grilla.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Grilla extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Grilla.this, VariablesPublicas.listado_grilla, R.layout.mylistrow,
                    VariablesPublicas.ColumnTags, new int[] {R.id.column1, R.id.column2});
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            //getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Object o = l.getItemAtPosition(position);
            VariablesPublicas.itemSeleccionado = o.toString();
            finish();

    }

}
```

mylistrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/column2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:text="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_grilla.xml (Grilla.java)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_grilla"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/mylistrow" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main application:

```
public class Main extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btn_buscarobra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buscarobra);

        btn_buscarobra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                servicioweb WS = new servicioweb();
                try {
                    String obras = WS.ObtenerObras("");
                    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = WS.XMLfromString(obras);

                    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");

                    //fill in the list items from the XML document
                    VariablesPublicas.listado_grilla = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("id_obra", servicioweb.getValue(e, "IdObra"));
                        map.put("obra", servicioweb.getValue(e, "Obra"));
                        //VariablesPublicas.listado_grilla.(new String[] {servicioweb.getValue(e, "IdObra"), 
                        //      }); 
                        VariablesPublicas.listado_grilla.add(map);

                    }   
                    VariablesPublicas.ColumnTags = new String[] {"#", "OBRA"};
                    Intent listaObras = new Intent(Main.this, Grilla.class);
                    startActivityForResult(listaObras,0);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });   
    }
```

When i click an item in listview it return the correct value.

Thanks!

Gonzalo.

Comment: You have your first TextView set to invisible; maybe the text in that one is long enough to push the second out of view, so you see nothing? Do you see any text if you remove the line `android:visibility="invisible"`?

Comment: The First "column" contains ID (that's why i set to invisible), if i set to visible, the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a key mismatch.

The keys in `VariablesPublicas.ColumnTags` should correspond to the ones in your maps.

Use either:

```
map.put("id_obra", servicioweb.getValue(e, "IdObra"));
map.put("obra", servicioweb.getValue(e, "Obra"));
...
VariablesPublicas.ColumnTags = new String[] {"id_obra", "obra"};
```

or:

```
map.put("#", servicioweb.getValue(e, "IdObra"));
map.put("OBRA", servicioweb.getValue(e, "Obra"));
...
VariablesPublicas.ColumnTags = new String[] {"#", "OBRA"};
```